# Automatically add files to SVN inside a specific folder

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I use TortoiseSVN to manage my SVN files. This all works quite well, but I have to manually add new files to SVN before I commit them.

In 99% of the cases that's exactly as wanted, but now I have a folder which contains logfiles that should be stored in SVN, but they are too dynamic to add them all manually.

So what I want is that I just commit the folder and all new files are automatically added and then committed.

I've seen a solution here, but not with TortoiseSVN.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but is it really a good idea to store log files in a svn repo? That usually doesn't make sense

Comment: This SVN command helped me find files that were not added and were not being ignored by the ignore rules (otherwise anytime i see unversioned files, they are ones i usually want to ignore). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927009/find-files-not-added-to-subversion

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the TortoiseSVN Commit dialog, select the "Show unversioned files" checkbox and then check "Select / deselect all". Now all your unversioned files are added. This is the closest you can come to "automatic" in TorsoiseSVN.

**Edit**
Wait a moment, there are actually [client side hook scripts](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-hooks) in TortoiseSVN. You can probably add a "start commit hook" that runs `svn add *` in the desired folder.

Comment: Worked! For all those, who need this too, the correct commandline for the hook script in TortoiseSVN is :`TortoiseProc.exe /command:add /path:"*" /closeonend:1"`

Comment: Just adding a note here to say be careful using the client side hook scripts, you will probably end up adding files you don't want on the SVN (Log files, .dlls, etc) if you aren't careful.

Comment: Why not use the glob to filter, e.g. *.cpp? In a real shell you can even do something like *.{h,cpp}