# Unversioned files not showing in version control panel android studio

Tags: android, svn, intellij-idea

I have enabled version control in android studio and also am able to see the repository history in version control tab the problem is when i created a file in project it doesn't shows in local changes or if i copied a file in project folder it doesn't shows in unversioned files but if added that files using tortoiseSvn after a refresh android studio will show that files,Is there any option that i have to enable do with android studio rather than using an extra client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Settings>Version Control>Confirmation, you can add/remove created/deleted files.

For tortoise, you can also check this : [Automatically add files to SVN inside a specific folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457410/automaticly-add-files-to-svn-inside-a-specific-folder)