# a bat file that list all files that are not added

Tags: svn, windows-7, tortoisesvn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find files not added to subversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927009/find-files-not-added-to-subversion)

We use `SVN` with `Tortoise` for our Visual Studio projects.Somtimes one of programmers add a file to project that it is not in repository and go home!
Is there a script to find all files that are not in repository(Not added)?

How about a plug-in for Tortoise?

**More**
as we know,first we must add file to repo which we can track it in SVN(commit,...)

Comment: ?? You description is hard to understand. Do you mean that he adds the file to his working copy but forgets to commit? If so, you'd need access to his machine.

Comment: They are trying to prevent it happening in the future by ensuring they commit everything to subversion.

Comment: I have flagged this as a duplicate, as the question I refer to in my answer is really a complete duplicate.

Comment: Answer direct link (in the duplicate question): http://stackoverflow.com/a/3959104/164089

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been asked before.

You can find solution to how to do this programatically [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927009/find-files-not-added-to-subversion).  There is a solution that uses SharpSvn which I re-post here:

```
SvnClient client = GetClient();

client.Status(workingCopyPath, (o, e) =>
{
    if(e.LocalContentStatus == SvnStatus.NotVersioned)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Not versioned: " + e.FullPath);
    }
});
```

Comment: is there way to add automatically?

Comment: I suggest you look at the SvnSharp library - I'm sure it will allow full capabilities to add and commit files.  You could write your own console application to run automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using TSVN, why don't you simply check the box "show unversioned files" at the bottom of the commit dialog?

Comment: only ignore files you really don't want versioned. Then you don't ever need to show them. But if you ignored all files, there's a checkbox for that too to show all the ignored files.