# Find files not added to subversion, except the Ignored files using SharpSvn

Tags: svn, sharpsvn

I want to get all unversioned files from a folder using the SharpSvn, that have the following svn:ingore value:

> *.o *.lo *.la #*# .*.rej *.rej .*~ *~ .#* .DS_Store thumbs.db Thumbs.db *.bak *.class *.exe *.mine *.obj *.ncb *.lib *.log *.idb *.pdb *.ilk *.msi* .res *.pch *.suo *.exp *.*~ *.~* ~*.* cvs CVS .CVS .cvs release Release debug Debug ignore Ignore bin Bin obj Obj *.csproj.user *.user *.generated.cs

I want to see all unversioned items to add to subversion. But, of course, I don't want to see the items from ignored list.

I tried to use the solution from the post: [Find files not added to subversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927009/find-files-not-added-to-subversion)  but it dowesn't work for me.

The code that get the status for items is following:

```
private IEnumerable<SvnStatusEventArgs> GetStatuses(SvnClient client, string work) {
     Collection<SvnStatusEventArgs> statuses;
     client.GetStatus(work, out statuses);
     return statuses;
  }
```

So, it returns the items from "ignore list" :(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show the code that you're using. What does "it doesn't work for me" mean? In what way does it not work? Does it not provide the desired results? Does it throw exceptions? Turn your oven into an icebox? Have you verified that SharpSVN is reading your global ignores in the first place, either from a config file or the registry?

Comment: Edit it into your post. Comments are not usable for code.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore list look like it not from svn:ignore property, but from svn config.

Possible SharpSvn load incorrect config?

Check property

```
client.Configuration.GlobalIgnorePattern
```

I try similar code (SharpSvn 1.8) and it is works correctly - does not returns ignored in config and svn:ignore

Comment: How can I set this property using SharpSvn?

Comment: Try use SvnClient.Configuration property for set real path to config.